# react-native run-ios and xcode build two different apps

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

Somehow it looks like the command

`react-native run-ios`

and running the Xcode project found with

`open ios/app.xcodeproj`

End up building two different apps (both icons are showing on the simulator).

The app built with Xcode throws the error

> Application app has not been registered

How do I go about solving this?

[image]

Comment: if you are using MAC, then can you try `sudo npm run ios`?

Comment: I don't have that script in npm, also running isn't the issue. `react-native run-ios` works fine, but it seems there's been a divergence. the above command should run the xcode project, but instead it runs either a subsection or an entirely different app. It's this issue I need help with

Answer (score 1):

**Follow this 2 Simple Steps Below**

1. Open Xcode, Product -> Clean
2. Press option key on your Mac Keyboard and hold down, then follow Product -> 'clean build folder'

**Now the time ReBuild**

**Thats All !**